# ¿Como puedo ver las librerías que usa GCC sobre C?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Tengo una duda sobre que librerías usa, ya que me quiero dedicar a usar solo C, pero quiero saber si usa otras librerías apartes de la estándar, y tambien si tinee una llamada graphis.h. Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué bibliotecas usa? Eso depende del sistema, no todos los linux usan el mismo conjunto. La implementación más común que te vas a encontrar recibe el nombre de "glib" que contiene una buena cantidad de utilidades además de las estándar. En cuanto a graphics.h hay más de una cabecera llamada así, cada una perteneciendo a una biblioteca distinta. Probablemente a ti te intereza la cabecera "graphics.h" de la biblioteca BGI, tipica de viejos compiladores de DOS. En ese caso puedes encontrar una implementación basada en SDL que funciona en linux.

Comment: Si quieres asegurar la portabilidad, las librerías estándar son las únicas en las que puedes y debes confiar, luego de eso, cualquier código o dependencia que escribas sobre las estándar.